# Create Landing Page in Drupal 7

Tags: drupal-7

In Drupal one can basically style the elements, like the search box, or the basic page etc. and then put some content in the site and the resulting page will be generated. But what if you want one specific site (e.g. the index page) to be different? E.g. have a image as a background, a different navigation styling etc.

What's the best paractice way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

- Best practice is to have a different theme which you can switch to by using [hook_custom_theme()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_custom_theme/7.x) where you check the current path. Also make sure that your theme to switch to is enabled:

  ```
  /**
   * Implements hook_custom_theme().
   */
  function YOUR_MODULE_custom_theme() {

      # check path with arg(0)

      # return theme name to switch to
      return 'different_theme_machine_name';
  }
  ```
- Alternatively you can also try [ThemeKey](https://www.drupal.org/project/themekey) doing this out of the box with an interface & allowing you the specify rules.

Comment: Thanks, I might look into that solution. I don't like using tousands of modules where I have no idea what they are doing. Also, I think it's rather strange to use a second theme but yeah - guess I just don't get the drupal way of doing things :P I'll look into it.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to change only the content(body) section of your page, use [Disply Suite](https://www.drupal.org/project/ds). You can create unique look and feel layouts for your body section of each page.

If you trying to change the complete layout of one page (eg: Services), Create new Content Type 'Services'. Then create a template file for this content type, You must name this template call page--services.tpl.php. And also you can overwrite the index page layout by creating page--front.tpl.php template. Done!

Comment: hmm, that's probably the drupal way right?I don't get it. I'd prefere to use as less module and stuff as possible. But thanks.

Answer (score 0):

What you are saying you want to change is all styling. And you know you can do a page to look drastically different with CSS... and you can do it that way depending on your chosen Drupal theme.

Now, with the Chrome Inspector (or FF inspector) look at the body tag, it probably has many classes which indicates in what page you are, what type of node (if it's a node) or if it's an admin section, or an anonymous user.

Using those specific classes you can style a frontpage, or a view, or a node, or anything, without installing more modules... with some limitations because you can't change rendered HTML this way.

Finally, don't get scared by using modules in Drupal, it's how Drupal works and it works pretty well. The thing is to install the best tools to increase your productivity, and Drupal have excellent options to change your theming and content like Display Suite (like @BaikHo suggested).

Hope that helps.

PD: Using the less module and with custom your theme you can have LESS css which is considerably faster than using only CSS, and because it's integrated with Drupal you can theme make everything even faster. Give it a try.